# What does Paul mean with "learn not to go beyond the things which are written;" in 1 Corinthians 4:6?

Tags: 1-corinthians

1 Corinthians 4:6 ASV Now these things, brethren, I have in a figure transferred to myself and Apollos for your sakes; that in us ye might learn not to go beyond the things which are written; that no one of you be puffed up for the one against the other.

Answer (score 1):

1 Corinthians 4:6 ASV

> Now these things, brethren, I have in a figure transferred to myself and Apollos for your sakes; that in us ye might learn **not to go beyond the things which are written**; that no one of you be puffed up for the one against the other.

It is a lesson of humility. Do not puff yourself up with exaggerated ways of knowing.

Philippians 2:3

> Do nothing out of selfish ambition or vain conceit. Rather, in **humility** value others above yourselves

Stay humble and objective. Don't go wild and over-interpret. Always willing to see from the other person's perspective.
This will free you from the warning in Proverbs 18:2

> Fools find no pleasure in understanding but delight in airing their own opinions.

Comment: Interpreting and advancing ideas not in the bible is right or not right? Please explain what "learn not to go beyond what is written means.

Comment: Is it done in humility?

Comment: I would like you to expound on the "learn not to go beyond what is written" part of the verse. Does being humble to you means you can go beyond what is written?

Comment: For me, I cannot stay humble and go beyond what is written.

Comment: I see that you consider yourself humble.

Comment: I'd like to be humble, but I'm not humble enough :) To me, humility is a freedom.